# how to get last row value of a column without considering the first row(header) using apps script(google spreadsheet)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have a column with a header (id) and i want to get the last row value of it so i can insert the next id automatically but i want the first row to be not considered (the header) i tried a formula inside the google sheet but when i delete the row 2 the formula breaks, here is the formula i tried:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),1,INDEX(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""),COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))) +1)
```

by the i enter all the data from an android phone

please help me
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Get Column Height

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```